# Installing modules with Julia

Tags: git, module, installation, package, julia

I am trying to install some the `Distributions` and `StatsBase` modules on a cluster but I fail. Here is what I did and the error message I got:

```
julia> Pkg.add()
ERROR: `add` has no method matching add()  # Not really relevant for our problem I guess

Pkg.add("Distributions")
ERROR: could not spawn `git version`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in _jl_spawn at process.jl:217
 in spawn at process.jl:348
 in open at ./process.jl:397
 in readbytes at ./process.jl:461
 in version at ./pkg/git.jl:34
 in init at ./pkg/dir.jl:32
 in __cd#227__ at ./pkg/dir.jl:28
 in add at pkg.jl:20

julia> Pkg.installed()
ERROR: could not spawn `git version`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in _jl_spawn at process.jl:217
 in spawn at process.jl:348
 in open at ./process.jl:397
 in readbytes at ./process.jl:461
 in version at ./pkg/git.jl:34
 in init at ./pkg/dir.jl:32
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:25
 in installed at pkg.jl:25

julia> Pkg.status()
ERROR: could not spawn `git version`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in _jl_spawn at process.jl:217
 in spawn at process.jl:348
 in open at ./process.jl:397
 in readbytes at ./process.jl:461
 in version at ./pkg/git.jl:34
 in init at ./pkg/dir.jl:32
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:25
 in status at pkg.jl:28 (repeats 2 times)
```

Should I just contact the guys that work for the maintenance of the cluster or can I solve this issue by myself?

Comment: Did you execute `Pkg.init()` first?

Comment: 'Pkg.ini' returns the same error

Comment: From the commandline, does `which git` or `git version` show that `git` is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you get Julia on these machines? Julia needs git for the package manager to work, and it seems like git isn't there. You'll probably need you cluster administrator to install it, or you could install the packages manually.